# Route that is executed within another route in Node.js is not being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http

Good Evening,
I have a function that contains a route that is a call to the Auth0 API and contains the updated data that was sent from the client. The function runs, but the app.patch() does not seem to run and I am not sure what I am missing.

```js
function updateUser(val) {

  

  app.patch(`https://${process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL}/api/v2/users/${val.id}`,(res) => {

    console.log(val);
    
    res.header('Authorization: Bearer <insert token>)
    res.json(val);
  })
  
  
app.post('/updateuser', (req, ) => {
  const val = req.body;
 
   updateUser(val);
  })
```

Comment: Do you understand that what `app.patch()` does is register a route handler on your server so that some FUTURE **incoming** http request with the PATCH verb might match that route handler.  It does not do anything right now other than register that route handler for the future.  Are you looking to SEND an http request to some other host and get the response back?

Comment: Yes I am looking to send a .patch(). The auth0 api uses the PATCH to update a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.patch()` does NOT send an outgoing request to another server.  Instead, it registers a listener for incoming PATCH requests.  It does not appear from your comments that that is what you want to do.

To send a PATCH request to another server, you need to use a library that is designed for sending http requests.  There's a low level library built into the nodejs http module which you could use an `http.request()` to construct a PATCH request with, but it's generally a lot easier to use a higher level library such as any of them listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

My favorite in that list is the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but many in that list are popular and used widely.

Using the `got()` library, you would send a PATCH request like this:

```
const got = require('got');

const options = {
    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${someToken}`},
    body: someData
};
const url = `https://${process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL}/api/v2/users/${val.id}`;

got.patch(url, options).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note: The PATCH request needs body data (the same that a POST needs body data)

Comment: I am going to try that and I will let you know. Thank you for the answer, that makes sense. I am not sure why that didn’t register, but I appreciate it.

Comment: The got library didnt work for me, but I actually just used axios and it works like a charm! Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, `axios()` is in the same general family as `got()` (a library for making http requests).  `got()` will work fine if used properly, but glad you got it figured out with axios.